# JWT Sign Issue using shell scripting

Tags: shell, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, service-accounts

trying to create a JWT file in order to request an access token to reach google analytics API.
Following this guide
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

I've created a service account and downloaded the private key and wrote some code (below).
I'm always receiving an error like this:

> "error_description": "Bad Request"

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the way I'm signing the JWT; to be sure I've also tried creating and uploading a signature (which was accepted by Google). But nothing changed.

```
echo $(date) - ===================START================================ >> test.log
echo $(date) - writing my JWT >> test.log
echo $(date) - ======================================================== >> test.log

#header
header=$(echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | base64) >> test.log
echo $(date) - JWT header: $header >> test.log

#epoch dates calculation
exp=$(date -d "+30 min" +'%s') >> test.log
echo $(date) - expiration time: $exp >> test.log 
iat=$(date +'%s') >> test.log
echo $(date) - issuing time: $iat >> test.log

#------------------
#payload
payload=$(echo -n '{"iss":"*myserviceaccount*","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly","aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","exp":'$exp',"iat":'$iat'}' | base64 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g') >> test.log
echo $(date) - payload: $payload >> test.log

#------------------
#sign
sign_alg=$header.$payload >> test.log
echo $(date) - sign string: $sign_alg >> test.log

firma=$(echo -n $sign_alg  | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private_key.pem | base64 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g') >> test.log
echo $(date) - encripted sign: $firma >> test.log

#token request call
#============================
JWT=$header.$payload.$firma >> test.log
echo $(date) - token request: $JWT >> test.log

echo $(date) - token call string >> test.log
curl -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=$JWT' https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token >> test.log

echo $(date) - ====================FINE ELABORAZIONE=================== >> test.log
```

here the additional code to obtain the certificate and the private key:
private key

```
openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 2048
```

certificate to be uploaded on google service account

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out cert.pem -days 999
```

someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT for future readers** I found two errors on my script and now it works

1. I need to url encode my string `| tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '=')`
2. apex :( my final call was

...&assertion=$JWT'

instead of

...&assertion='$JWT

Please note te position of '